# Regex of account number, only accept numbers and hyphens

Tags: regex

The account number should start with a number and end with a number. Within the numbers, hyphen is accepted. Noted that hyphen should not repeat (--, --- etc). 
Now I can validate the examples 1-4, how to deal with the case 5-6?

```
^[0-9][0-9\-]*[0-9]$
```

**For example**

1. 324324-324324-23432 is TRUE

2. -2342343-2432-3214324 is FALSE

3. 324324-324324- is FALSE

4. 3dsfsdf4324-324-324 is FALSE

5. 324324--324324- is FALSE

6. 324324--3243-24 is FALSE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a negative lookahead assertion.

```
^[0-9](?:[0-9]|-(?!-))*[0-9]$
```

The `(?:)` is a non-capturing group. In it we accept either a digit, or we accept `-(?!-)`, which means a hyphen that is not followed by another hyphen.

Note that not all regex engines support lookahead assertions, but most do.

---

If you're using an engine that doesn't support negative lookahead assertions, you can also do this by using a regular expression that specifies that every hyphen must be followed by a digit.

```
^[0-9](?:-?[0-9])*$
```

This one does have one difference from the previous in what it matches, which is this one will accept a single digit (e.g. `3`) as the input but the other one requires at least two digits.

Answer (score 0):

```
^\d?(?:\d{1,}\-{1})*\d+$/
```

You can use this also.

Answer (score -1):

```js
var input = `
324324-324324-23432
324324-324324-23432-11111
-2342343-2432-3214324
324324-324324-
3dsfsdf4324-324-324
324324--324324-
324324--3243-24
`;

console.log( input.match(/^[0-9]{5,}-[0-9]{5,}-[0-9]{5,}$/gm) )
```